# .setItemChecked equivalence in swift

Tags: java, swift, xcode, android-studio

I am wondering how to convert some java code into swift. I've looked online but I haven't found anything useful. I found j2objc but I have no idea how to get it to work. I only need one line of code translated.

```
                        listView.setItemChecked(myArrayList.indexOf(myName);
```

what is .setItemClicked in java equivalent to in swift?

Simply, I have a list view where if an object is queried from Parse and it's true, put a check mark next to the object in the list view. But I don't know how to check something off in a list view without clicking on the item in swift. How do I make a check mark appear in a list view without having to click the item in the list view?

Comment: If you can search and implement with this keyword `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`, let do it. Otherwise, post your code here, and I will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: this only applies to Swift 2.2

The iOS equivalent of `ListView` is `UITableView`. The Swift equivalent for `ArrayList<>` is `Array`. And there are no such methods as `setItemChecked` in the iOS API.

The closest that I can think of is `UITableViewAccessoryCheckmark`. However, you can also put a `UISwitch` in the table cell and set its `on` property to true.

Let me show you how to set the accessory type of a table cell to `UITableViewAccessoryCheckmark`, or in Swift terms, `.Checkmark`.

First, you need to get the table cell. To get it, you need an `NSIndexPath`. `NSIndexPath` is basically an object describing which section and which row the cell is in. Assuming your table view has only one section, you can create an index path like this:

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(
    forRow: myArray.indexOfObject(myName), 
    inSection: 0)
```

Note that `indexOfObject` will return a weird number when the object is not in the array. And if the same object appears in the array more than once, it returns the index of the first appearance.

Now you have an index path, you can get the cell now:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

Then, just set the `accessoryType` property:

```
cell?.accessoryType = .Checkmark
```